# Prove that every element of E is equal to a product of primas.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I initially had not problem understanding what it wanted from me. However, earlier in the book it said

> Let E be the set of all positive even integers. We call a number *e* in E "prima" if *e* cannot be expressed as a product of two other members of E.

Is this not contradicting what it is asking me to prove? I used 6 as an example as 6=2*3, while 2 is a prima, 3 is not as it is not in the set of E. I emailed my instructor and he messaged me this:

> Be careful about how things are defined.
>
> E is the set of all positive even integers, and there is a subset of E that consist of the prima integers.
>
> For instance, both 4 and 6 are in E, but 6 is prima while 4 is not.
>
> You want to show that every element of E (that is, every positive even integer) is a product of primas.
>
> 4=2x2, and 2 is prima.  6 is prima so it is a product of one prima (namely, itself).
>
> It is analogous to noting that even though 10 is not prime, it is product of two primes (2x5) and 7 is a product of one prime (namely itself).

This did not provide any clarification to me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So why do you feel that $6$ cannot be written as a product of primas, for example? Note  that while you usually take the product of two element, the "one element" product is just the element itself, so for example $6$ is the product of every element of the set $\{6\}$.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Since $6$ is itself prima, it is already written as a product of primas (just as a single prime, in the ordinary sense of the word, is a product of primes).  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: I understand that primes can be a product of primes (3 is 3*1), but 6 is not a product of primas as it is 2*3 with 3 not being a prima, so I don't understand.

Comment: @AmyKulp Note using the elements of the set $E$ for multiplication means that *only* elements of this set are considered when multiplying to check for the members being a "prima". If you're allowed to consider numbers outside of the set, for example, then $3$ wouldn't be considered prime as it's the product of $\frac{3}{2}$ and $2$. Likewise, you can't consider $6 = 2 \times 3$ because $3$ is not in $E$, thus it's not even a "contender" to check on, much less worry about whether or not it is considered to be a "prima".

Comment: @JohnOmielan I have to consider 6 though as it is in the set of E. I can't just skip past it. Therefore 6 HAS to be a product of primas, but it's not.

Comment: @AmyKulp Sometimes in math, when using a plural form, the singular is implied as well. This is the case here and, as I explain in my comment to my answer below, what is sometimes used for the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. I've seen this used several times and, I too, initially found it a bit confusing. This is why many definitions of the unique factorization say things like it being a prime or a product of primes, but sometimes mathematicians take short cuts. As another example, consider a factorial being a product of integers from $1$ up. However, $1! = 1$ is still a factorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ being a set of all positive even numbers means each element has at least one factor of $2$. Thus, the product of $2$ elements of $E$ would have at least $2$ factors of $2$ and, as such, any element with only $1$ factor of $2$ cannot be a product of $2$ elements. By definition, this means these numbers are all "prima", including $2$, $6 = 2 \times 3$, $10 = 2 \times 5$, etc. These elements are all products of primas, namely just the $1$ prima of themselves.

Each $e \in E$, where $e$ has $2$ or more factors of $2$, can be written as $e = 2^n m$, where $n \ge 2$ and $m$ is an odd integer. In these cases, $e = 2 \times 2^{n-1} m$, where $2$ and $2^{n-1} m$ are each a member of $E$. Thus, this shows that, by the definition, these elements are not considered to be prima, e.g., $4 = 2 \times 2, 8 = 2 \times 4, 12 = 2 \times 6$, etc. Also, note that $e = \left(\Pi_{i=1}^{n-1} 2\right)\left(2m\right)$, where $2$ and $2m$ are each primas, so $e$ is a product of primas, e.g., $24 = 2 \times 2 \times 6$.

As this covers all of the cases, it shows that all elements of $E$ can be written as product of primas. However, note that unlike with primes, the set of prima factors is not unique for any integers where $2$ or more factors of $2$ and $m$ having $2$ or more prime factors. For example, $60 = 2 \times 30 = 10 \times 6$.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. You said that any element with only 1 factor of 2 cannot be a product of 2 elements which means 6 would not be a prima.

Comment: The definition you've provided says "We call a number *e* in E "prima" if *e* cannot be expressed as a product of two other members of E." Note that, in *this* system, $6$ cannot be expressed as the product of any $2$ elements of $E$ since it has only $1$ factor of $2$. Thus, by the *definition*, $6$ is a "prima". However, in our regular number system, of course, $6$ is not "prime", but this is a different definition using a different set of elements (i.e., all integers, not just even ones). Please think about this carefully. Can you find $2$ even integers which multiply to give $6$?

Comment: I understand 6 is a prima, that is not what's confusing me. What is confusing me is no, there are not two even integers that give 6. There's 2*3 and 1*6, but neither of those have two even integers.

Comment: If you understand that $6$ is a prima, I'm not quite sure what is confusing you. As you said, $6$ cannot be expressed as a product of $2$ even integers, i.e., elements of $E$. This applies to $6$ & also to all even integers with just $1$ factor of $2$. As I show above, numbers with $2$ or more factors of $2$ may be expressed as a product of $2$ and an element with just $1$ factor of $2$, each of which are "prima", so they're not prima themselves but are a product of prima numbers. I've changed my answer to clarify elements with $2$ or more factors of $2$ are a product of $2$ elements of $E$.

Comment: @AmyKulp I've also added a few specific examples in my answer. I hope this helps to better see what's going on.

Comment: I have to show that every element in E is a product of primas. 6 is not a product of primas. 6=2*3, 2 is a prima, 3 is not in E. So that is not a product of primas. 6=6*1, 6 is a prima,, 1 is not in E. So that's not a product of primas which contradicting what I have to prove.

Comment: @AmyKulp I think I'm beginning to understand the issues. First, note that, as I tried to explain in a comment to your question, *only* elements of $E$ are considered for checking a number being a "prima". Thus, odd integers like $1$, $3$, etc., aren't an issue. Also, when it talks about a product of "primas", note the "s", i.e., plural, is not necessarily the case. It could be **just** one number. For example, one statement of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that each integer $\ge 2$ is a unique product of primes. However, this includes just $1$ prime. This is what's meant here.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you so much for the help and being nice about me not understanding.

Comment: @AmyKulp You are welcome. I'm glad you understand now. Math has its own language that takes some getting used to.